# Run script with timeout and redirected output and then do something with output

Tags: bash, timeout

I am trying to save analyze the output of a script that might not terminate. In order to do so I redirect the output to a file and run the script together with timeout follows by my analyze command, cat in this case.

```
timeout 24h php phpscript.php > script.out && cat script.out
```

But this does not seem to work, the output is written to the file but is never printed. I have tried wrapping the timeout command in parenthesis like so;

```
(timeout 24h php phpscript.php > script.out) && cat script.out
```

without any result. 
It seems to me that this should be trivial but my bashfu is weak.

Please help

Comment: can you try like timeout 24h php phpscript.php >> script.out && cat script.out

Comment: @thinkingmonster not really sure where you wanted me to put it but i tried every position to no avail.

Comment: are you writing to stdout  in php script

Comment: @thinkingmonster I'm printing with echo and the output is available in script.out, the problem is just that its not echoed out to the screen with the cat command

Comment: Can you try with tailf script.out instead of cat

Comment: when you run the cat command ,at that time your file was empty so nothing displayed and cat will not show updated data until you reopen the file with cat..I guess tailf command will work for you

Comment: @thinkingmonster same as before I'm afraid, assuming you meant tail -f

Answer (score 0):

The problem turnes out to be the exit code.

Timeout return 124 as exit code while the && composition only evaluates the second argument when the exit code of the first was 0

solution:

```
timeout 24h php phpscript.php > script.out || cat script.out
```

Answer (score 0):

no this problem doesn't come from the exit code because same occures with the `--preserve-status` switch.

I thinks this is due to output buffering enabled on stdout and timeout cuts the subprocess before it is flushed. So you should be able to disable it with `stdbuf`

Your solution would be is :

```
timeout 24h stdbuf -o0 php phpscript.php > script.out && cat script.out
```